# Disable steps count in iPhone 6

Tags: ios, iphone, health.app

Today I opened Health on my iPhone 6 and I realized that it is counting my steps.

However I never enabled this functionality.

Is there a way to disable it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not a feature that you need to enable. The co-processor starts tracking when you switch on your phone. To answer your question, Health app does not track your steps, it merely only shows you the data that is fed from the co-processor and other health related apps. I'm afraid it's something which cannot be switched off.

Some developers over at the jailbreak community have tried to disable it - it's worth taking a look if you're interested in that sort of solution.

Answer (score 5):

iOS 8 has Settings => Privacy => Motion & Fitness => Fitness Tracking (On/Off). I don't know if it works; it was on when I just discovered it, yet Health app can't find any motion data. I *do* walk ...

Answer (score 0):

This data has been counted in previous iPhones too. (Starting from 5s), it's only made visible now. I wonder why this became a problem now?

There's currently no way to disable this built-in pedometer.

Comment: iPhone 5S was the first to have a motion coprocessor (M7), so definitively not since the 4S.

Answer (score -2):

In Health, you should visit the **Steps** settings under **More** then **Steps**, and change the setting to **Don't track steps**. It should stop counting!

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks, can you please be more detailed? I cannot find te settings you mentioned.

Comment: These are steps for an app called "MyFitnessPal", so not a valid answer.